# Numbered string in bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to define numbered string in series in bash such as follows:

```
String1
String2
String3
String4
String5
```

What I did till now is as follows which it does not work well.

```
#!/bin/bash
str_name='String'
for i in `seq 1 5`
do
expr=$(($str_name + $i)) #this part is what I cannot deal with it.
echo $expr
done
```

Thanks

Comment: _"it does not work well"_ - you'd help the guys here by saying _what_ doens't work! f.e.: Error Messages? What is the output you get?

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "String"{1..5}`?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is adding variables in an arithmetic sense. You want to use the following:

```
expr="${str_name}${i}"
```

**Note:** It's not necessary to surround the variables with brackets. I just do it because it's easier to read *sometimes*, it also keeps me from making stupid mistakes.

To go into more detail, `$(...)` executes anything between the parentheses in a sub-shell and returns the results. I'm not sure what output you where getting when echoing `$expr`, but I gather it was an error message. Something like `Command String + 1 cannot be found` but I really don't know.

Comment: No errors: here it's not about `$( ... )` but about `$(( ... ))`, which is an arithmetic expansion, not a command substitution. In OP's case, `String` is undefined, hence expands to `0` in arithmetic, so the expansion `$expr` is `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` respectively.

Comment: You're completely right @gniourf_gniourf - don't know what I was thinking. I'll edit my last paragraph out. Do you mind if I add your comment to my answer, with attribution?

Answer (score 0):

You even don't require echo in another line. try this.

```
#!/bin/bash
str_name='String'
for i in `seq 1 5`
do
echo $str_name$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

*Brace Expansion* is another manner in which you can iterate over a range:

```
for i in {1..5}; do
    printf "String%d\n" $i
done
```

For example:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do printf "String%d\n" $i; done
String1
String2
String3
String4
String5
```